how to get the IP address of the cluster using k0s
how do I get the IP from k0s?
I cannot use kubectl get svc clusterip because k0s doesn't have clusterip

Which IP address(es) in particular?  Kubernetes by design is a multi-node environment.  Why do you need an IP address and not a DNS name?

I'm running it in single node, I'm exploring the "how-to" options, I'm just surprised that I can't find an equivalent of "minikube ip" command

You can use k0s kubeconfig admin to get access to the cluster. The kubeconfig file will contain the right URL. Also, k0s has an embedded version of kubectl (à la k0s kc get po -A) which will use the admin kubeconfig by default.
